# Use PowerMTA to warm up an external smtp server

Tags: email, warm-up, powermta, pmta

i am using powermta to dispatch bulk and transactional emails using couple of virtual mtas mapped to different local virtual NIC's to go out from different IP's.
my question here is. in my transactional section of the pmta configurations can i map an external smtp server (which is a simple exim server) to warmup it using the configurations of pmta and once the threshold reaches dispatch normally from the current vmta's listed in the transactional section.
is that doable? and what directives can help me reaching my target? any configuration suggestions will be appreciated.

Not sure if there are any straight forward configurations to do it.

Comment: You should probably ask port25 support.

Comment: No! This isn't doable. There could be certain ways to but things will get complex quickly, involving piping and port remapping/forwarding.